# How to save inner objects with MERGE

Tags: java, neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j-4

For now I am using save method from **GraphRepository** and I also have constraint on user id, it is **unique**. User have List of users - friends. 
My flow:

1. Read from db, if user is null save his with friends, I am using **save** method from **GraphRepository**
2. But if user is present i just  need to update him and update his friends.
   I am using custom query into DAO method

   ```
   @Query("MERGE (u:User {id:{user}.id}) " +
       "ON CREATE SET u.id = {user}.id, u.firstName={user}.firstName, u.lastName={user}.lastName, u.imgUrl = {user}.imgUrl  " +
       "ON MATCH SET u.id += {user}.id, u.firstName+={user}.firstName, u.lastName+={user}.lastName, u.imgUrl += {user}.imgUrl")
   void mergeUser(@Param("user") User user);
   ```

   But with merge method i can't add all user's friends and **ON MATCH** case doesn't work too 
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use a Cypher query that looks something like this:

```
MERGE (u:User {id:{user}.id})
SET u.firstName = {user}.firstName, u.lastName = {user}.lastName, u.imgUrl = {user}.imgUrl
WITH u
UNWIND {friends} AS friend
MERGE (f:User {id:{friend}.id})
SET f.firstName = {friend}.firstName, f.lastName = {friend}.lastName, f.imgUrl = {friend}.imgUrl
MERGE (u)-[:FRIEND_OF]->(f);
```

There is no need to use `ON CREATE` or `ON MATCH`, since you always want to do the same thing either way. Also, there is no need to explicitly assign to the `id` property, since `MERGE` will guarantee that the node will have the desired `id` value.

I assume that `friends` collection consists of maps that have the same keys as your `user` map.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but after merge it looks not as i expected, look screanshot above

Comment: You need to provide more information about the parameters you used, and what you wanted the result to look like.